# List reverse Ocaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I'm creating a function that reverse a list.
I think all is good but the compiler isn't of the same opinion...
This is the code :

```
let reverse list_ =
 let rec support list_ =
 match list_ with
 | [] -> []
 | hd :: tl -> support tl :: hd in
 let return = support list_ in return
```

The error is :

```
| hd :: tl -> support tl :: hd in

Error: This expression has type 'a list
   but an expression was expected of type 'a
   The type variable 'a occurs inside 'a list`
```

My idea is to reach the end of the list than I'll build a new list from `[]` adding the latest elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you that `support tl` has type `'a list` while the `::` operator works like this: `1 :: [2;3] = [1;2;3]`. Conceptually what you are trying to do is `[3; 2] :: 1`, which is not how the operator works.

If you want to append `hd` at the end of a list you need to use the `@` operator (or the [append](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html#VALappend) function):

```ml
let reverse list_ =
  let rec support list_ =
    match list_ with
    | [] -> []
    | hd :: tl -> support tl @ [hd] in
  let return = support list_ in return
```

Now the problem is time complexity, we are iterating through the entire list for each element. To deal with this we can use a list on which we accumulate the elements:

```ml
let reverse list =
  let rec support acc list_ =
    match list_ with
    | [] -> acc
    | hd :: tl -> support (hd :: acc) tl in
  let return = support [] list in return
```

This code could be rewritten a bit considering that:

- the expression `let return = support [] list in return` is the same as `support [] list`
- `let some_fun some_val = match some_val with (* ... *)` can be written as `let some_fun = function (* ... *)` omitting `some_val` entirely

```ml
let reverse list =
  let rec support acc = function
  | [] -> acc
  | hd :: tl -> support (hd :: acc) tl in
  support [] list
```

I guess that using `match` or `function` is just a matter of personal preference though.

Comment: It works thank you! But I don't understand what you did..."| hd :: tl -> support (hd :: acc)  tl" means : "if there is an head and a tail call support with the list (hd::acc)" why you set a "tl" later? "Support "has only 1 argument...I didn't get it

Comment: I know I can use "@" but I was looking for a self-made function

Comment: @MichealRoss `support` actually has 2 arguments, I hope it's clearer now!

Comment: Ok with "match" all is clear, without "match" using "function"?

Comment: `support` has this type signature `'a list -> 'a list -> 'a list`, so `support (hd :: acc) tl` means roughly "call support with `hd :: acc` as first argument and `tl` as second"

Answer (score 2):

The operator `::` is not symmetric. It takes a list element at the left and a list at the right. In this expression:

```
support tl :: hd
```

You have a list at the left (the result of the recursive call) and a list element at the right. So that's not going to work.